# Setting a popup to only appear if the user hasn't submitted the form in the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, popup

I'm not sure how best to approach this, but this project would require a popup to appear. The popup would display an iframe that has a donation form linked to an external database. Ideally, this popup would only appear if the visitor has not yet donated.

Since I don't have direct access to this external database (form is provided by the client), I thought, maybe, the popup could utilize HTML localStorage (found a [working demo here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24189694/745514)) taking it a step further to check if that form had been submitted (storing info from the form action?) for that visitor. This stored cookie would then expire every 6 months.

Is this even possible or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think it is possible, since we're talking about localstorage which is stored in the browser. Try to create a fiddle, and lets see what you got

Comment: If you have control of the form submission button, you can use localstorage to save a date and check the date every time the page loads. I can get you some code, but again, you have to have control over the form, this wouldn't work.