# How to implement cookie popup in Spring for first-time users

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cookies

I Googled it but I can't seem to find an example code to implement cookie notification for first-time visits of my website (prompt that shows the site uses cookies).

How can I implement one in Spring MVC (easy and clean way)?

Comment: I don't think there is an 'easy' way to do this. Maybe store consent by using ip ?

Comment: It is a notification and users cannot accept or refuse it. Just to inform first visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case, you might have different solutions. For instance :

**Easy** **solution** is using the [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the consent.
Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189428/display-a-popup-only-once-per-user#answer-24189694) for an exemple on how to use it.

*Advantages* : Easy to implement. No server code required.

*Inconvenients :* Requires that the client uses a [compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Browser_compatibility) browser. You might want to test if the `window.localStorage` is present. Also you can ignore old browser and always display the popup for these.

**Hard option** is to send to your server the consent, the server then stores the user ip address for example along with consent. Next time, the user visits your website, the consent is fetched to see if user let you store cookies.

Finally you could tune the hard option using the user login if the user has logged on your website so that the consent is saved across devices.