# Popup newsletter form opens every time when reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add a automatic popup newsletter form to my static website(usinng google spreadsheet to collect mail). But when page reload every time popup shows up. I want something like if anyone press **Subscribe** or **Not Now** button popup will stop forever for their device. Is it possible?

I used this code. But When I reopen the browser Newsletter popup shows again.What I need to change here?

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        if ($.cookie("dismiss") == null) {

            $('.modal').appendTo("body");
            function show_modal() {
                $('.modal').modal();
            }

            window.setTimeout(show_modal, 300);
        }

        $(".close").mouseenter(function () {
            document.cookie = "dismiss=true";
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi Shoyeb, can you share your code? Would be helpful to see your implementation

Comment: Learn about localstorage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189428/display-a-popup-only-once-per-user

Comment: I edited Question and added some code. Now please .

Comment: @DanielGrima Can u help me?

Comment: @ShoyebMohammedSuny please look at the answer I posted to see one way that you can tackle it. I'd suggest to use local storage and not cookies. Anyway if you'd like to use cookies can you explain what `$.cookie` is? I haven't used jQuery in a while, but I don't think that is jQuery - is that some third party plugin you are using? maybe this could help you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-a-cookie-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle this using local storage. [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

With local storage you can save information that is not lost after a refresh. (Similar thing can be done with cookies, but in this particular case I think local storage fits your use case)

So you can try doing something like this:

```
// save item
localStorage.setItem("isUserSubscribed", true);

// get item
localStorage.getItem("isUserSubscribed");
```

Note that local storage items that are not set will return a `null` value.

In short every time the page loads execute `getItem()` and based on that value run the logic that you need.